# Navigation graphs for Angular SPA

Tags: angular, navigation

I am building an SPA using Angular and I'm looking for a way to abstract the flow of control through the UI as a service rather than having it hard-coded into the components.

Instead of

```
onContinue() { 
    if(this.isNewPayment) { 
        this.router.navigate(["somewhere/something"]) :
    } else {
        this.router.navigate(["somewhere/something-else"]);
    }
})
```

I want

```
navService.begin("newPaymentProcess");
...
onContinue() { this.navService.next(NavActions.Continue); }
```

Configuration for the navigation service will define the allowable paths through the UI as nodes in a set of graphs, each graph typically representing a use-case of the application.   It will hold a mapping of nodes to routes, have abstractions for actions that invoke a navigation and it will support nesting of graphs.

Is there anything ready-made for Angular or will I have to write this service myself?

In the past have seen this done in desktop apps using BizTalk to map the flow, and in web sites using in-house components that represent the navigation graphs using xml.  I believe Google has something similar for Android apps too.